# how to create List<UserModel> by string name like "UserModel"

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have model name like

> UserModel

i want create List of UserModel by string variable with "UserModel" value like

```
string className = "UserModel";
List<className> users = new List<className>();
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the type which is generic argument. You can either use `Type.GetType` if you have a fully-qualified name, or use `yourAssembly.GetType` if you know full name and assembly:

```
string typeName = "System.Int32";
var genericArgument = Type.GetType(typeName);
```

Now, you can create a `List<T>` type of this type using `.MakeGenericType`:

```
var genericType = typeof (List<>).MakeGenericType(genericArgument);
```

And now you need to instantiate this `List<T>`:

```
object result = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now i want create function and return result

Comment: how can use List Methods ?

Comment: @mohsenfathi You cannot use List methods directly, without reflection, because you don't know the type at compile time.

Comment: To access the methods you might use `dynamic`. It does the reflection for you but you will be in danger of run-time exceptions if you use incorrect methods.